# C# console application and web browser automation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using a C#.net console application, is it possible to find a Chrome window with a specific Url in its address bar, open a new Chrome tab in that window and then Automating that tab? By automating, I will then load a specific URL and then do few clicks programmatically. I tried using Selenium Web driver, but it does everything else except identifying the Chrome window with a specific URL and opening a tab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp 
There's already something similar.

Comment: Asked and answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177076/all-open-chrome-windows-using-selenium-chrome-driver/41178227 Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean asking again will yield a different one.

Comment: Better understand the question before passing comments like this. This question is clearly about recommendation about Selenium alternatives while the other question was strictly about how to do that using Selenium chrome driver.

Comment: Can you give a few more details on why it has to be a new tab? I believe this can be done, but wouldn't just be easier to open another browser? Navigating between tabs is a bit like navigating between frames and it can be a real pain. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587533/open-a-new-tab-in-an-existing-browser-session-using-selenium) and see if it helps.